# Jquery Datatable search using a form

Tags: jquery, datatables

table and i want to search it client side using a search form and its column filtering or using any plugin/technique .
I have tried to find it on goggle but its just giving me each column filtering .
i have following form : 
[image]

i have a form in which form row is equal to data-table column and i need to implement `and` and `or` functionality to search.

Please help , thanks :)

Comment: Can you give us bit more details, and where you are struggling?

Comment: You want to implement search in dataTable right?

Comment: Right, through a form.As you can see in above picture.I m struggling how i will implement the condition and and or .

Comment: I don't know and I think still i didn't understand your problem,but from the form just send those params to serverSide and get that back, or you are struggling to right the query? or you are finding difficultly in get those search parameters?

Comment: ok let me make it more clear .. i have thousands of record on my table i want to search it on client side not on server side .and i am using a plugin jquery datatable .. so i want to know if there is any provision in this plugin to achieve solution of my problem .thanks fr your time :)

Comment: But search is only possible by the combination of both client and server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fnFilter API method of DataTables ( http://datatables.net/api#fnFilter ) to apply a filter term to the table.

Comment: Hi Allan Please Help me , Hoe can i search using OR operator .. is there any inbuilt functionality to achieve that ???

Comment: hi @sarveshkushwaha, you have a example ?